# two windows 7 boot options in boot menu

Tags: grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 dual boot. After GRUB repair two Windows 7 boot options are appearing. Both are booting the same Windows 7 OS. The system recovery partition is appearing as separate partition in My Computer.

I read from Ubuntu help, the older GRUB files are saved in system recovery partition. How can I remove older GRUB files from system recovery partition with removing system recovery files.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both booting to the same OS then I don't see a huge problem, my solution simply involves editing the grub menu in order to get rid of the other option. First of I would check your `grub.cfg` file. This can be accessed typically via the following commands:

```
 cd /boot/grub/
 **insert favorite text editor here** grub.cfg (you may need root access to perform this operation)
```

This is an important file to your system, so messing with it is not advised unless you know what you are doing, hence the `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE` at the top of the file.

In terms of your question, we are going to be removing a `menuentry`. Scroll through this file until you find something resembling the following:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2 *this may be different depending on the computer*)
```

The following lines are important, if I am right about this file there should be two of these `menuentry`'s and **THEY SHOULD BE THE EXACT SAME**. A simple solution would be to remove one of the entries. I will emphasize this again **THEY MUST BE THE SAME**. A good move would be to make a copy of this file and save it somewhere where you can access it in case of a failure. Something like:

```
cp grub.cfg ~/
```

This should solve your problem. I would advise against removing the old GRUB files in the recovery partition as it could cause some problems later, unless they are causing problems now.

Comment: Everything is there as you said above. I have removed the complete line and some content below the line. It's working well now and only one Windows 7 boot option is appearing. I didn't save the duplicate file. Will it show any problem in the future?

Comment: @RameshManda You shouldn't have any problems foreseeable problems in the future. If everything is working well right now, nothing should change that later on. I'm glad I was able to help!